# How can you trigger the YouTube App from Instagram’s “swipe up” feature?

Tags: url-rewriting, youtube-api, instagram, redirect, instagram-api

So basically, I have seen many Instagram (IG) users that have the swipe up feature available on their accounts. However, when they send you to a YouTube (YT) link, it’s an internal website to IG.

Due to this, users of IG are not logged into YT and able to “like” or subscribe from this screen. I wanted to help these users get more activity on their channels by getting people logged in with less effort, but can’t figure out how and have been researching for days.

The simplest idea I can think of is to trigger the opening of the YT app, but I’m not sure if that’s possible. The next would be to trigger the user to login as that typically brings you to the YT app.

So, is there a way to structure the URL of YouTube to either:
 A) force the YouTube App to open?
  or
 B) force the login on a specific video?

If not, is there a way to structure a separate website to contain JavaScript that triggers one of these options?

Any help would be most appreciated.